# the Cell.add(" Cell Content ") does not work in Itext7 version 7.1.12 . is is this from me or from the Itext7 ? here are some codes

Tags: java, itext7

```
Cell SubTitle = new Cell().setBold();
Cell CA1Title = new Cell().setBold().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
Cell CA2Title = new Cell().setBold().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
Cell ExamTitle = new Cell().setBold().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
Cell TotalTitle = new Cell().setBold().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
Cell RemarkTitle = new Cell().setBold();
SubTitle.add("Subject");
CA1Title.add("1st C.A");
CA2Title.add("2nd C.A");
ExamTitle.add("Exam");
TotalTitle.add("Total Score");
RemarkTitle.add("Remark");
```

The method `Cell.add()` doesn't accept argument(`String`).

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In iText, not all elements can accept just "simple" text - some elements are containers for other "Block" elements, whereas the `Text` is a Leaf element. Actual text is represented by objects of `Text` or `Paragraph` type:

```
Text text1 = new Text("Text 1");
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(text1);
Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Text 2");
```

The `Cell` itself (as its [documentation](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.12/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Cell.html) says) is simply a container that holds other elements (and provides col/row spanning for Tables). So to add text to it you need to give it a `Paragraph` element to hold onto:

```
Cell myCell = new Cell()
    .add(new Paragraph("My Cell Title"))
    .setBold()
    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if if solves your problem, so the question shows up as answered for everyone else.